# Is there a direct link to an AppStore search result on iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'd like to link to all apps as if the user had opened the Apple App Store and searched for "Authenticator". Is there an iOS specific link that would facilitate this like the itms://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/twilio-authy/id494168017 link that opens a specific app.
Google has this URL https://play.google.com/store/search?q=authenticator&c=apps but I can't find an iOS equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now found this link which seems to do the job

itms-apps://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=authenticator

Answer (score 2):

Try the link as below,(here when your click on a specific app ,it will open on App Store)

https://www.apple.com/us/search/Authenticator?page=1&sel=explore&src=globalnav

Comment: So my QA team discovered that if the Apple store app is installed, then you instead get taken to the Apple store app and are presented with a printer you can buy https://ibb.co/2K0wWxF. Any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: I'm also had Apple store app.But in mine,the link open in the safari 1st and then when click on a specific app,it will open on App Store.(note that : in the safari page it shows the Apple Store option.But when click a specific app it will open on App Store.).[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZEuh1hwibITLNthrJoYUXdn7sjHxALZ/view?usp=sharing)